# Creating easy-to-read short links to the App Store for your apps and company

Tags: mac-app-store

I have several games published on Mac App Store, and I want to add a link to show on Mac App Store all my games.

I followed the advice from :
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1633/_index.html

My company is Green Sauce Games, I tried two links :

http://appstore.com/mac/greensaucegamesltdame

- The link does not work as expected! It opens Mac App Store but shows "Cannot Connect to App Store" in an infinite loop (I click ok and the message appears again), I have to Force Quit the App Store.

http://appstore.com/mac/greensaucegames

- The same, but the message is "App Not Available in Your Country or Region" also in an infinite loop.

Even testing the examples in the article, I have the same problem in all.

Has anyone succeeded or knows how to do it correctly?